# Passing total post count to javascript

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, ajax, javascript, taxonomy

I have a ajax post loading program, I can load more post on click of a button.

Problem im having is getting the button to hide or show less when no more post.

I can query out the post count in PHP as i have with my side bar bellow.

```
      <?php foreach ($my_categories as $term_id) {
            $category = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'category');
        
            if($category->slug!="all-articles") {
                if($category->parent != 0){ // If this is a subcategory

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category' => $category->term_id,
    'post_type' => $new_string,
);
$count_posts = get_posts( $args );
$total_posts_child = count($count_posts);


  ?>
          <li :class="category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'child' : ''" ;>
                     <a class="child" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name ); echo " ". "(" .$total_posts_child . ")"; ?></a>
                </li> <?php
    
    } else {
   
                
                $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category' => $category->term_id,
    'post_type' => $new_string,
);
$count_posts = get_posts( $args );
$total_posts_parent = count($count_posts);

 ?>
      <li :class="category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'parent' : ''" ;>
                     <a class="parent" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name); echo " ". "(" .$total_posts_parent . ")" ?></a>
                </li>   <?php
    }
          
            }
        }
```

Problem im getting is trying to get that post count into Javascript so i can hide my button if post count is reached.

```
 <div @click="loadMore()" x-show="total > (limit + offset)" class="text-center pt-4">
                 <button class="border border-solid border-slate-700 text-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-800 px-4 py-2"> Load More </button>
            </div>
```

here is my javascript

```
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 6,
    category: null,
    post_type_js: post_id,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    offset: 0,
    total:null,
    
    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.total = 8;
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
    loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.total = 8;
        this.offset += 6;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },

    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
        formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); 

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
            formData.append("total", this.total);
        }

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        });
    },
    
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal();
}

}));
})
```

I have thought about scraping my HTML and getting the number, but honestly been thinking all day, I cant find a way to get the total post count for the category and post type clicked in the side bar